# Refactoring golang Struct and Functions

Tags: go

I have found this code online as a challenge and apparently there is something wrong with the design, its considered bad design. Could anyone tell me the problems with this and how you would refactor it?

```
type User struct {
    Uuid      string
    FirstName string `db:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `db:"last_name"`
    Email     string
    Password  string
    Address   *Address
}

type Address struct {
    Uuid     string
    UserUuid uint `db:"user_uuid"`
    Address1 string
    Address2 string
    City     string
    Postcode string
}

func OrderBYAndGetAll(orderBy string) ([]User, error) {
    db, _ := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=prod password=prodPass741 dbname=acme sslmode=disable")
    getUsersQuery := "SELECT * FROM users"
    // Add the order by if it has been passed though
    if orderBy != "" {
        getUsersQuery += " ORDER BY " + orderBy + " ASC"
    }
    users := []User{}
    db.Select(&users, getUsersQuery)
    // Find the address for each user
    for _, user := range users {
        db.Select(&user.Address, "select * from addresses where user_uuid = "+user.Uuid)
    }
    return users, nil
}

func GetAllUsers() ([]User, error) {
    // db, _ := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=dev password=password dbname=acme sslmode=disable")
    //  getUsersQuery := "SELECT * FROM users"
    //  users := []User{}
    //  db.Select(&users, getUsersQuery)
    db, _ := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=prod password=prodPass741 dbname=acme sslmode=disable")
    getUsersQuery := "SELECT * FROM users"
    users := []User{}
    db.Select(&users, getUsersQuery)
    // Find the address for each user
    for _, user := range users {
        err := db.Select(&user.Address, "select * from addresses where user_uuid = "+user.Uuid)
    }
    return users, nil
}
```

Comment: both function has database connection inside it, this could be moved to separate function  and use returned db instance . then in query could use prepared parameters to avoid possible sql attacks. last thing there is the loop will make multiple query.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I have never tried `sqlx` but this code aims for extendable, reusable, and reducing resource consumption.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

type User struct {
    Uuid      string
    FirstName string `db:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `db:"last_name"`
    Email     string
    Password  string
    Address   *Address
}

type Address struct {
    Uuid     string
    UserUuid uint `db:"user_uuid"`
    Address1 string
    Address2 string
    City     string
    Postcode string
}

type IStorage interface {
    GetUsers(orderBy string) ([]*User, error)
}

type sqlxConn struct {
    *sqlx.DB
}

func NewSqlxConn(driverName, dataSourceName string) (IStorage, error) {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect(driverName, dataSourceName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &sqlxConn{DB: db}, nil
}

func (s *sqlxConn) GetUsers(orderBy string) ([]*User, error) {
    getUsersQuery := "SELECT * FROM users"
    // Add the order by if it has been passed though
    if orderBy != "" {
        getUsersQuery += " ORDER BY " + orderBy + " ASC"
    }
    users := make([]*User, 0)
    s.Select(&users, getUsersQuery)

    if len(users) == 0 {
        return users, nil
    }

    // Find the address for each user
    var uuids []string
    for _, user := range users {
        uuids = append(uuids, user.Uuid)
    }

    addresses := make([]*Address, 0)
    s.Select(&addresses, "select * from addresses where user_uuid IN ("+strings.Join(uuids, ",")+")")

    for _, address := range addresses {
        for _, user := range users {
            user.Address = address
        }
    }

    return users, nil
}

func OrderBYAndGetAll(storage IStorage, orderBy string) ([]*User, error) {
    return storage.GetUsers(orderBy)
}

func GetAllUsers(storage IStorage) ([]*User, error) {
    return storage.GetUsers("")
}

func main() {
    conn, err := NewSqlxConn("postgres", "user=prod password=prodPass741 dbname=acme sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(GetAllUsers(conn))
}
```